# Angular HTTP POST Response giving 404 Not Found Error in Staging but working in Local

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a Angular UI Portal that interacts with a REST Service. I added couple of more endpoints to the existing REST service. The new endpoint services are tested from Swagger and Postman with 200 Response. Also, I get 200 response when I hit the service from angular UI in my Local. But receiving "404 Not Found" when deployed on Staging Server in PCF. The other endpoints in the same service return success.the error response from Chrome Dev Tools...

```
error: {timestamp: "2020-08-13T19:36:44.354+0000", status: 404, error: "Not Found", message: "No message available", path: "/updtPOShipStatus"}
headers: e {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://ipaddress: 404 Not Found"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "https://ipaddress/updtPOShipStatus"
```

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    })
  };

  public updatePOflagStatus(poShipStatus: PurchaseOrderFlagStatus) : Observable<any>{
    const poShipStatusRequestBody = {
      poShipStatus : poShipStatus
    };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.updateShipStatusUrl, poShipStatusRequestBody, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

I am unable to replicate the problem in Local as well. Please help.

Comment: welcome, its obvious  what your problem is not programming problem, you can check your firewall and network privileges

Comment: I am able to successfully hit the existing endpoints. If it is the case of firewall/ network issue, then I shouldn't have access to any of the endpoints in that service.